# Search value from Input box in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to search the username from table by using form method in HTML with submit button, and what i really want is that when user write his email address in input box and press submit, the query should echo username associated with that email address.

But the problem is that when I press search button, it is showing all the usernames on that table instead of only one. My table "payments" containing the following values: id, product id, payer_email, username, password.

My code is as under. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

   // Database Connection String
   $con = mysql_connect($db_hostname,$db_username,$db_password);
   if (!$con)
   {
       die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   mysql_select_db($db_database, $con);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <form action="" method="post">  
           Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />  
           <input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
       </form>  
       <?php
           if (!empty($_REQUEST['term'])) {

               $term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['term']);     

               $sql = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE payer_email LIKE '%".$term."%'"; 
               $r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

               while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
                   echo 'Username: ' .$row['username'];  

               }  

           }
       ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have multiple  usernames with that email

Comment: You are checking `$_REQUEST['term']` and then trying to use `$_REQUEST['payer_email']` - which isn't set!  They should both use `term`.  You should also use prepared  statements - which also means you need to STOP using the `mysql_` api.

Comment: woow..by changing ```$_REQUEST['payer_email'] ``` to ``` $_REQUEST['term']``` solved my problem. Thanks a lot @NigelRen you saved my day. i will be very appreciated if you please check if any other bug if any in my code which needed to be fixed because i want to implement this on my sensitive project.

Comment: `mysql_connect`?? that api was deprecated years ago

Comment: i am using that code on php version 5.5. so i think that was still fine for me.

Comment: PHP 5.5 has been out of support for years as well. You need to upgrade

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
    <?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['payer_email'])) {

$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['payer_email']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM payments WHERE payer_email ='{$term}'"; 
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r_query)

echo 'Username: ' .$row['username'];  

}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is your expectation ?

Comment: i have edited my code and now every thing is working fine, but now i am facing one more problem. when i write email address in input box, it is successfully showing username associated with that email, but when i write something like 1, or anything other than email in input box and hit submit, then it is showing all the usernames available in that table. anyone who tell me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Swayangjit
I want to extract the associated array associated with this email with this code. When we provide the exact email information there is no need to use the like and since we want an array there is no need for a loop, I hope I get it right.

Comment: @Alex
When you use like, it displays whatever looks like your search, you should search for exactly the email you want by matching the search value with the relevant field